# C# Is there a difference between Enum ToString and nameof Enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I'm tryinng to get the text from a enum e.g.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    Bar,
    Foo
}
```

In this case, get the string `Bar` or `Foo` using `MyEnum.Bar` / `MyEnum.Foo`.

I realized that both `MyEnum.Bar.ToString()` and `nameof(MyEnum.Bar)` will return the string that I want (`Bar`/`Foo`).

So my question is, is there a difference between using `ToString` or `nameof`?

If yes, what is the recommended way of using it?

Comment: According to [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#nameof-expressions) _A nameof_expression is a constant expression of type `string`, and has no effect at runtime_ `ToString()` is virtual call, made in runtime

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: In this case, though, they're still equivalent, as enum constants won't change their name at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference is that `foo.ToString()` is evaluated at runtime, and `nameof(foo)` is a compiler feature and thus the string is baked in at compile-time.

The second difference is that they are, in principle, different things: `ToString()` is a method that merely returns a “text-representation of the object”, which is a pretty weak guarantee, while `nameof` gives you the name of whatever you pass into it, as written in the source code.

For enum constants the way you're comparing the usage there's little difference, though apart from `nameof` being technically a bit cheaper. But there are a lot of things where the name isn't actually the identity or preferred string representation of it and `nameof` is actually more intended to create refactoring- or rename-safe references to named things that may end up in strings somewhere. Think of exception messages referring to a parameter name, or `INotifyPropertyChanged` referring to a property name as a string.

My recommendation would be to actually write your intention. If you want the name of a particular type or member, use `nameof`. If you want a string representation of something, use `ToString`. Most of the time you don't have the luxury of being able to use `EnumConstant.ToString()` anyway, since it's more likely to have something in a variable, in which case `nameof` won't have any benefits, except if you want the name of that variable.

Comment: This merits repeating: "... since it's more likely to have something in a variable, in which case nameof won't have any benefits, except if you want the name of that variable."

Comment: I'm wondering, though, whether calling `.ToString()` on my enum's members won't keep creating new string instances all over the place, that will then have to be garbage-collected later on. In that circumstance, I'd much prefer the compiler generated constant.

Comment: Funny enough, I just found this benchmark screenshot on exactly this topic: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gferreira_dotnet-activity-6871842280320368640-2xUc. Unforunately, it doesn't show the allocations used for all of the .ToString() calls. Still, using `nameof()` instead of `.ToString()` looks like an easy decision to me.